# Integral curves

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Suppose $f$ is a vector field. Let $g$ be an integral curve whose domain contains $[0,\infty)$. Now $\lim (g(t)) =p$ as $t \to \infty$. Then can we say that $f(p)$ is zero?

Comment: NIce question.  I edited it to $LaTeX$ify your math. I also added he "differential equations" tag. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Robert for latexifying it and adding the tag.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that $f$ is continuous in all its variables, and each of the components of the integral curve are continuous.  Let $g_i(t)$ be the $i$th component of the integral curve, and $f_i$ the $i$th component of $f$, and $p_i$ the $i$th component of $p$.  Since $g_i(t) \to p_i$ we get that $|g_1(n+1)-g_1(n)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  Using the Mean Value Theorem from Calculus we have a $n \leq c \leq n+1$ such that $$ |g_i(n+1) - g_i(n)| = |g_i'(c)| = |f_i(g_1(c),g_2(c),\ldots,g_m(c))|.$$  Taking limits as $n \to \infty$ (and thus as $c \to \infty$) on both sides and using continuity this implies that $$ \lim_{c \to \infty} |f_i(g_1(c),g_2(c),\ldots,g_m(c))|=0 \Rightarrow |f_i(p)|=0$$
since $\lim_{c\to \infty} (g_1(c),g_2(c),\ldots,g_m(c))=p$.  So $f_i(p)=0$ for every $i$, and thus $f(p)=0$.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. So the guess is correct. I have just started reading integral curves,  flows etc. Please suggest a nice book where I would get a lot of simple problems to really know what's going on and a lot of pictures. Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. Preference is a non text book though would like to know what are the text books.

Comment: A useful answer to a good question.  But note:  I think you want to refer to the ***Mean Value Theorem***--https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem --rather than the ***Intermediate Value Theorem***--https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem --.  Just a tip to make a great anwer ***perfect***!  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis, thanks.  It is a mistake I make too often.  I guess I always think "Well, c is an intermediate value...".

Hili, though it is a textbook, Strogatz's "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" is considered one of the best introductory texts on the subject.  If you want a stronger analytical treatment "Differential equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra" by Hirsch and Smale is where I learned everything I know.  It also has lots of examples early on.

Perhaps someone else can recommend a text from a more geometrical or topological view?

Comment: Again, I wish to congratulate you on presenting a *really nice* and *very good* answer to this question, which I have thought about on and off for quite awhile but never got around to solving.  Though elementary, I have found it enters into many an investigation of ODEs, so I'm glad to see/know how the solution works.  As for books, I too am well-familiar with Hirsch, Smale (and now Devaney's, right?) text, and have myself found it quite useful.  As far as geometrical treatments are concerned, you might check out Witold Hurewicz's *Lectures on Ordinary Differential Equations*--more follows!

Comment: More follows ***here:***  Hurewicz's book is pretty ancient at this point, but very clear and pretty damn geometrical.  And of course, what I call the "granddaddy*--Jack Hale's *Ordinary Differential Equaions*--a modern classic.  Keep up the good work.  Cheers!

Comment: Will surely check out the books mentioned. Many thanks to both Robert and  Kareem.